# Плагин intl-tel-input, выбор страны для номера телефона, ошибка в модальном окне

Tags: jquery, frontend, плагин

требуется помощь.

Плагин https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input.
Сайт для примера: https://protohumix.com/ru?modal=registrationModal
В модальном окне, если открыть страны, то при повторном клике на флаг или вне формы, не закрывается dropdown. Так же если закрыть модальное окно, с открытым dropdown стран, отключаются нажатия клавиш, вне поля ввода телефона.

Незнаю как быть, помогите пожалуйста.
При это всем, на странице обычной, работает все корректно.

Вызов плагина аналогичен обычному вызову на странице.

```
$('#registrationPhone').intlTelInput({
        preferredCountries: ["ua", "ru", "us"],
        autoPlaceholder: "polite",
        initialCountry: "UA",
        placeholderNumberType: "MOBILE",
        utilsScript: "/js/utils.js",
    });
```

Возможно посоветуете аналогичный удобный плагин для подключения, но этот покрывает все потребности.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему, добавив кода в плагин, рядом со строкой назначения слушателя:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", this._handleClickOffToClose);
```

```
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
for (var i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
   modals[i].addEventListener('click', this._handleClickOffToClose, false);
}
```

Аналогично в функции `_closeDropdown`, для удаления слушателя.